# Passing client created object to server .net remoting

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

How can I pass my client-side object to my server object in .net remoting?

This is how I'm doing my test.
On my class library:

```
public interface IServer 
{
  bool SubmitMessage( ISampleClass sample ); 
}

[Serializable]
public Server : MarshalByRefObject , IServer 
{
   Public Server() 
   {
   }
   public bool SubmitMessage( ISampleClass sample )
   {
     return true;
   }
}


public interface ISampleClass 
{
  string GetName();
}

[Serializable]
public class SampleClass : MarshalByRefObject , ISampleClass
{
  public SampleClass()
  {
  }
  public string GetName()
  {
    return "test";
  }
}
```

On my Server Application:

```
IChannel channel = new TcpChannel(9988);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel,false);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisteredWellKnownServiceType( typeof(Testing.Server) ,"testremote",WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterActivatedServiceType(typeof(Testing.SampleClass));
RemotingConfiguration.ApplicationName = "TestRemote";
```

On my Client Application:

```
Type type = typeof(Testing.Server);
Testing.IServer server = (Testing.IServer)Activator.GetOject(type,"tcp://localhost:9988/testremote");
RemotingConfiguration.RegisteredActivatedClientType(typeof(Testing.SampleClass), "tcp://localhost:9988/TestRemote");
Testing.SampleClass test = new Testing.SampleClass(); // proxy class
server.SubmitMessage(test); // Error here
```

The error I encoutered was:
    Because of security restrictions, the type System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef cannot be accessed.
    Inner Exception: Request Failed.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out already what I'm doing wrong. The SampleClass should not have inherited the MarshalByRefObject.

May be this can be of future reference to others.